# Is a residence permit required for an accompanied (newborn) minor to leave the EU?

Tags: indian-citizens, borders, eu, permits

My son was born in Sweden 5 months back. I am taking him to India this month on vacation. He has his Indian passport but no residence permit yet (applied and waiting for decision).

Will I face any problems when exiting the EU with him?

I intend to bring him back to Sweden only after receiving his permit.

UPDATE: Apparently, a resident permit is required even when leaving the EU if the border control happens in an EU country that is not your country of residence. In our case, the border control was in Berlin where we changed flight to Delhi. The officer said that there is a fine for illegal immigration even if for a single day, but he is going to waive it as we had documents supporting the application for residence permit for my son.

Comment: Permits and visas are typically required when entering a country, not when leaving. The only reason they might want it is to check overstay. In your case your son is a minor, you are traveling with him. Minors traveling with their parents cannot be charged with overstay. You're worrying over nothing at all.

Comment: +1 for @SheikPaul, but another thing you need to keep in mind is that you might not be able to collect the residence permit while you're abroad, how are you planning to handle that?

Comment: @downhand I have asked the migration board to send the residence permit to the Swedish Embassy in India.

Comment: If you ask on [Expatriates.SE], you are more likely to find someone with similar experience to answer the question.

Comment: I've edited the title because newly born babies often get special treatment when they're born in a country that doesn't grant citizenship. (Similarly, the child of a US immigrant doesn't need an immigrant visa if born after the parent's visa was issued.)

Answer (score 1):

Permits and visas are typically required when entering a country, not when leaving. The main reason they might want it in this case is to check overstay and/or trafficking of a minor. In your case your son is a minor, you are traveling with him. Minors traveling with their parents cannot be charged with overstay.

https://www.gov.uk/permission-take-child-abroad

Make sure you have permission from his mother (if you're the father).

Comment: Those who downvoted, can you please explain why?

Comment: @Prometheus Good luck getting an answer.